# Defining setter for Ember Object property

Tags: object, ember.js, properties, set

I have an Ember.Object `Foo` with property `message`:

```
Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    message: null
```

When `this.set('message', value)` is executed, I want to modify the `value` variable before it is set on `message`.

I can do this with `.observes`:

```
Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    message: null,
    messageSetter: function() {
         this.set('message', this.get('message') + 'suffix')
    }.observes('message')
```

OR I can use a `computed property` and even handle `getter` then:

```
Foo = Ember.Object.extend({
    messageValue: null,
    message: function(key, value) {
        if(arguments.length > 1) {
             this.set('messageValue', value + 'suffix');
        }
       return this.get('messageValue');
    }.property('message')
```

But both look kinda messy, is there a cleaner way to modify value before it is set on property?

Comment: Not that I know of, this is what computed properties are for.

Answer (score 0):

The second example in your post is what you want to do, but you have a type-o. You should bind to `messageValue` as in `}.property('messageValue'}`.

However, if you do not care about the original input value of `message` you can have some fun with computed properties. The value that a CP returns will become the value of that CP. So, you could simplify this to something like:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jimuvaji/1/edit

But really you should use your example #2.